# How can I resolve ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed Error?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I'm trying to connect the Codeigniter framework to the Oracle 18C database to create some kind of API that I will use to develop a mobile application.

I have already accomplished to create the model and controller and also edit the database.php file in the Codeigniter to match the Oracle 18C database.

But when I try to start the Codeigniter application below error displayed in the webpage.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Make sure php_oci8 extension is loaded in php.ini
and can you provide us the content of the database.php?

Comment: @SoufianeLamnizeh I'll try to load that oci8 in the php.ini of apache. I've added the content of database.php, is there something wrong with it?

Comment: are you using the express version of oracle ?

Comment: @SoufianeLamnizeh Yes, I'm using Express Version of Oracle 18c. I already uncomment the oci8 in php.ini but there's still no changes in the error.